# How can I get Pinch to Zoom back in Desktop mode?

Tags: windows-8

Windows 7 had an old implimentation of Pinch to Zoom where bringing your fingers apart/together would act similar to <kbd>ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>+/-</kbd>, the standard zoom. It's not as nice as granular zoom (like iOS/Android use) but it worked. Most notably it doesn't work in Chrome (did before) but I haven't noticed it working in any other apps. In windows 8 desktop mode, pinch to zoom doesn't seem to work at all. It doesn't even work in One Note 2010, which, if I recall correctly, had granular zoom in Windows 7.

I have an (older) 2 touch point multi-touch monitor, and I can see the visual feedback that the two touch points and coming closer/farther apart, but it doesn't zoom. Note I'm using the touchscreen, not a touchpad or the Arch mouse or other peripherals.

Can I enable this somehow or is it gone from Desktop mode? It works fine in Metro apps. Additionally I get weird visual feedback when placing my second finger on the screen; a shrinking transparent square appears somewhere between the two fingers, visually similar to the Right Click visual queue when long-pressing. It's not a right click though, I can't tell what, if anything, it's doing.

Comment: Which computer manufacturer are you using? Is this PC hardware or Mac hardware?

Comment: Are you using a touchscreen or trackpad? Win8 doesn't have any Synaptics drivers installed, you have to install (the Win7 ones) themselves. (There are no Win8 trackpad drivers yet.)

Comment: @mcandre It's a Lenovo X200 tablet, so PC hardware (Mac has never made multitouch screens for OSX anyway)

Comment: @ACarter it's a multitouch screen, not a trackpad

Comment: @Ben Ok, I can't be any help then :(

Comment: @BenBrocka True, but that doesn't stop people from making "hackintoshes" out of Mac OS X and spare computer parts.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to your settings ui. Then do a  search for  "tablet mode" that should give u pinch to zoom back on in windows 8.1 and 8 (and 10)...

Answer (score 0):

If you can manage to get Aero by some [tweaks](http://betanews.com/2012/09/07/get-aero-on-windows-8/) that are available online you may get Pinch to Zoom back. Haven't tried myself though.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://kentwng.wordpress.com/2012/07/24/windows-8-rp-on-thinkpad-x200-tablet/) claims that you can install the Wacom Bamboo drivers to get Win 8 touchscreen features to function. Without an X200 or a Win 8, I can't test it out but hopefully it's true.